# Tomcat properties configuration file location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm new to Java (around 2 months Java experience after coming from a .Net background). I've been asked to support a Java application which uses Spring, J2EE, and an Oracle database.

We have an issue with our deployment process which I'm struggling to understand.

The Java application in question has database connection details in an application.properties file. Its location appears to be configured from a Spring configuration file using the following line:

```
<context:property-placeholder       location="classpath:config/application.properties,classpath:config/bookings.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

On our Development Tomcat server, the application (called Bookings) looks in this location for the application.properties file:

/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/Bookings/WEB-INF/classes/config

Which is what I would expect, looking at the Spring configuration.

However, on Production Tomcat, the application looks in a different location:

/usr/share/tomcat/lib/config

(In this directory, the file is called bookings.properties.

The original developer has left the company and I have no idea why it would look in a different location for the file (and a different filename).

Any ideas what I can look at, or where this could be configured? It should be noted that both files (application.properties and bookings.properties) are present on both Tomcat servers, so I don't understand the discrepancy?

We have re-deployed the same WAR file to both development and production, and the discrepancy still exists, i.e. the servers still look in different places.

Answer (score 1):

[classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) is a directory where you could put some resources (to make it simple, further details on the link).
that's a variable and it's added to the launch command, sometimes it's a bit hidden. But that's the way it works.

May be you can watch in $TOMCAT_DIR\bin\catalina.sh to see how the classpath is defined.
In your case, the folders contained in your classpath are different between development server and production server. That's totally normal.

However, you say that in production the file is named bookings.properties.
But with this line :

```
<context:property-placeholder       location="classpath:config/application.properties,classpath:config/buyer-request.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

we see that you never try to load a file named booking.properties. 
So ask yourself why the file is called booking.properties. And rename it application.properties to see what happen.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Apologies that config line was incorrect in the post, I corrected it now, but it should have been bookings.properties. So I think it is looking for the right name for the file, just the location appears to be different. I will check the $TOMCAT_DIR\bin\catalina.sh to see what's in there, maybe that will help.